# Changing forked repo from mirror to origin

Tags: wordpress, git, github, git-fork

My team had forked a repo that was actually a mirror used to display the code for wordpress users. We updated some things in the wordpress plugin by forking this repo and when trying to push our changes back to that mirror we were given an error message:

> This repository is just a mirror, pull requests are not monitored or accepted here. Please look at the official page for instructions on how to contribute changes back to this plugin. If none exist, we suggest posting a new topic to address this on the support forum on WordPress.org.

The original link was then given to us and I tried changing the url in the .git/config file (as suggested here: [how to sync a repo mirror to a new upstream repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247881/how-to-sync-a-repo-mirror-to-a-new-upstream-repo)) to the new repo but was given a 403 error:

> error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing https://github.com/shanaver/social-hashtags/info/refs
>       fatal: HTTP request failed

I have a feeling there are other steps that must be taken, but I'm fairly new when it comes to github.

Of course I can just fork the new repo and paste in all the code that we worked on but we would like to not overwrite all of the various author's works and commit history in this change.

Comment: Trimming 'info/refs' off the URL will get you https://github.com/shanaver/social-hashtags/ which is the repo you should submit pull requests to. Is that what you're trying to accomplish? I ask because you also mention being new to github and not wanting to overwrite other author's works ... you won't be able to push to anything but to your own fork unless you're given Collaborator access by the repo owner to the original repo, but you can submit a Pull Request to it.

Comment: We do not want to overwrite the various authors' work and commits in the fork that was originally made from the mirror. We want to **push** these changes to the new repo that is not a mirror preserving the changes that those authors made from the mirrored repo. This way we can update the actual plugin and still show which code is from each author.